# Global array won't update, keeps giving garbage values when passed by reference

Tags: c, multithreading, global-variables, mergesort, garbage

It's supposed to call a function through a thread for merge sort- but for some reason, it doesn't update the global array when I try to output it later through the main() function. So i tried passing it by reference but that only made it give out random values instead, using `int *array []` made it give positive random values instead of negative ones. I've been trying to figure out why it does that but currently have got nothing

Any clues on why it is behaving like this or how to update the global array would be appreciated.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int array[] = {3,4,6,2,6,8,2,9,3,1};

void merge(int array[], int l, int mid, int  r)
{
    printf("merge is running\n");   

    int size1 = r - mid;
    int size2 = mid- l+1;

    int left[size1];
    int right[size2];

    for(int i =0; i< size1; i++){
        left[i] = array[l+1];
    }
    for(int j =0; j< size2; j++){
        right[j] = array[mid + 1 +j];
    }
     
    int index1= 0; 
    int index2 = 0; 
    int index3 = l;

    while(index1 < size1 && index2< size2){
        if(left[index1] <= right[index2]){
        array[index3] = left[index1];
        index1++;
        }
        else{
        array[index3] = right[index2];
        index2++;
        }
        index3++;
    }

    while(index1 < size1){
        array[index3] = left[index1];
        index1++;
        index3++;
    }

    while( index2< size2){
        array[index3] = right[index2];
        index2++;
        index3++;
    }
}

void MERGESORT(int array[], int start, int end)
{
    if(start<= end){
        printf("mergesort is finished\n");
        return;
    }

    int mid= start + (end - start)/2;
    MERGESORT(&array, start, mid);
    MERGESORT(&array, mid+1, end);
    merge(&array, start, mid, end);
}

void *thread_fun(void *arg)
{
    int oldstate, oldtype;
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, &oldstate);
    printf("you are now in the thread\n");

    int start =0;
    int end = 10;
    MERGESORT(&array, start, end-1);
    printf("merge is done\n");
    printf("sorting finished\n");

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    printf("main is being executed\n");
    pthread_t tid1;
    char message[] = "this is a threadddd";
    pthread_attr_t threadat;
    pthread_attr_init(&threadat);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&threadat, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    pthread_create(&tid1, &threadat , thread_fun, (void*)message);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&threadat);
    int joinflag = pthread_join(tid1, NULL);

    if(joinflag==0){
        printf("join successful\n");
    }
    else
        printf("join failed\n");

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("the array now contains: %d \n",&array[i]);

    }       
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `start<= end` true right away?

Comment: it isn't- its actually sorting the random numbers correctly but it won't use the ones i've hard coded or taken input for

Comment: Calling `MERGESORT()` with `&array` as a first argument is wrong. `MERGESORT()` accepts a pointer to an `int` (yes, `int array[]` is resolved to `int *array`), and not a double pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Having a global variable `array` passed to a function with a parameter named `array` is likely to cause confusion.  If you compile with GCC, use the `-Wshadow` option to avoid such (possible) problems.  Also, it is aconventional to use an all-caps name for a function.  Such names are usually used for macros and enumeration constants.

Comment: Follow this: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) Then pay attention to all the warnings and errors generated.

Comment: You are missing `#include <pthread.h>`

Comment: For future posts consider reducing the content to contain just what is necessary to illustrate the core issue you are interested in having addressed, in this case that appears to be why the array is not being updated.  Other issues can be addressed in a new post if needed, but when all of them are presented together, it becomes messy and confusing to deal with, and often results in downvotes, when all you wanted was help on the one simple issue. ( [mcve] )

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Remove all the `&` in front of `array` and it should work.

An array is always passed by reference: think of the array as an `int` pointer.
With an array declared like this `int table[]`, using the variable `table` is exactly the same as using `&table[0]` -> The array variable directly points to its 1st element. The previous statement might sound weird, but you always modify the array itself when passing it to a function.

Using `&array[i]`, you actually print the address of the i'th element, the same applies when calling the function `MERGESORT()`.

Comment: yes that is how i initially did it- but that ends up with the array not updating at all

Comment: @MRDZ Have you tried calling directly `thread_fun()` to see if the issue could be thread usage related?
I would also personally rename the variable `array` to something like `table`, just to be sure it does not conflict with something else.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Any clues on why it is behaving like this or* **how to update the global array** *would be appreciated."*

When boiled down (beside dealing with the warnings and errors already mentioned, which will go a long way toward some of the unwanted behaviors.)  the stated need is to address how to pass an array argument such that it can be updated by the function.

The following is not to address your function implementations.  The comments have already pointed out that calling methods used in the example code for `MERGESORT()` are not compatible with its prototype,  The following is stripped down to illustrate two simple functions, each taking an `int` array, and the number of elements in the array  Each modifies the array and returns.

Note, the methods used to change `array` contents are not important, only that they do change the contents, and that the prototypes are able to convey the address of the array's modified memory block back to the caller.

Two methods:

```
int array[] = {3,4,6,2,6,8,2,9,3,1};

//qsort support
int compare (const void * a, const void * b) 
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
//method 1 (passes pointer to address of first element of array, and count of elements)
void change_array(int *arr, int count)//note pointer argument
{                                     
    qsort(arr, count, sizeof(int), compare);
}
//method 2 (uses array notation argument, and loop assignments to modify)
void change_array_again (int count, int arr[])//note order of arguments
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i+1;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int count = sizeof array/sizeof array[0];
    change_array(array, count); //using qsort
    change_array_again(count, array); //using hardcode assignments
    
    return 0;
}
```